# Extracting Certain Rows From Imported Data in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset that I loaded into R using the `readLines()` command, the structure is `chr`. That data is oringially imported from a CSV file with a combination of strings characters in some line and, data in other. The dataset I am trying to extract is in rows 15 to 37. I tried using `read.table(data[15:37],sep=",",header=F)` but I keep getting the error: `Error in file(file, "rt") : invalid 'description' argument`. I tried using `data.frame(data[15:37],sep=",")` command to parse out the relevant dataset but unfortunately with no luck. What am I doing wrong?

**Update:**

So I have the starting row and the ending row for which my data presides in

```
start=c(13,103,202,250)
end=c(102,201,249,300)
```

So the first block of data is between rows 13 and 102 , inclusive. Same for the second block of contigious data, starts at row 103 and ends at 201.

I am trying to create a loop where I can pull the data using the `dataset_{#number}=read.table(text=data[start:end],sep=",",header=F)`

```
n=1
for (i in start){
dataset_{n}=read.table(text=data[i:end[n]],sep=",",header=F)
n=n+1
}
```

How do I tell the loop to create a brand new data set to save each contiguous block?? How do I tell R that {n} is not a string but part of the loop??

Comment: Some clarification would help. Have you already read in "data" as a dataframe? If so the command you want is `data[15:37,]`. Note the comma.

Comment: The data was read using the readLines() command. It was 4000 rows and 1 column. So I cannot use the comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`read.table` fails to open a `file` connection to read the source data. Try a `text` connection:

```
data <- readLines(textConnection("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer nunc metus sem et dui. Curabitur nibh
Donec convallis laoreet id Vivamus wisi Nunc nec metus.
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8"))
rowsToExtract <- 3:4
read.table(text=data[rowsToExtract], sep=",", header=F)
# V1 V2 V3 V4
# 1  1  2  3  4
# 2  5  6  7  8
```

**@Update:**

Consider the following sample data:

```
data <- readLines(textConnection("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer nunc metus sem et dui. Curabitur nibh
Donec convallis laoreet id Vivamus wisi Nunc nec metus.
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8
Lorem ipsum
9,10,11,12
13,14,15,16"))
start <- c(3,6)
end <- c(4,7)
```

You would probably want to use a `list`, which you could create using (a.) your loop:

```
dataset <- list()
for (i in 1:length(start))
  dataset[[i]] <- read.table(text=data[start[i]:end[i]], sep=",", header=F)
dataset
```

Or (b.) using something like `mapply`:

```
mapply(function(from, to) read.table(text=data[from:to], sep=",", header=F), start, end, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```

The result:

```
# [[1]]
#   V1 V2 V3 V4
# 1  1  2  3  4
# 2  5  6  7  8
# 
# [[2]]
#   V1 V2 V3 V4
# 1  9 10 11 12
# 2 13 14 15 16
dataset[[1]]
#   V1 V2 V3 V4
# 1  1  2  3  4
# 2  5  6  7  8
```

However, if you don't want to work with a `list`, try:

```
for (i in 1:length(start))
  assign(paste0("dataset_", i), read.table(text=data[start[i]:end[i]], sep=",", header=F))
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Luke. But the data I am pulling in is being called on from my computer as: "C:\\Users\\..\\filename.csv". I cannot just wrap the just use textConnection(C:\\Users\\..\\filename.csv)

Comment: I expressed myself misleading; you just need to change `read.table(data[15:37],...)` to `read.table(text=data[15:37],...)`

Comment: Thank you so much Luke!! I am updating the question for another quick follow up question.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how you read in the data, but if you are impoarting a csv, you could just use:

```
mydata = read.csv("mydata.csv")  # read csv file 
mydata                           # print data frame
```

- now you can use dataframe options;

you can access your data with the comment `mydata[15:35,]`

@readLines {base} :"Read some or all text lines from a connection.":

you could try `mytable<-read.table(textConnection(mydata))` for a data.frame