# Feeding Loop Elements into String Objects in R

Tags: r

So I have two vectors (they are actually the starting rows and the ending rows for which my data presides in in another R object)

```
start=c(13,103,202,250)
end=c(102,201,249,300)
```

I am trying to create a loop where I can pull the data using the `dataset_{#number}=read.table(text=data[start:end],sep=",",header=F)`

```
n=1
for (i in start){
dataset_{n}=read.table(text=data[i:end[n]],sep=",",header=F)
n=n+1
}
```

Desired Output:

```
dataset_1
dataset_2
dataset_3
..
```

How do I tell the loop to create a brand new data set to save each contiguous block?? How do I tell R that {n} is not a string but part of the loop??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `assign`:

```
for (i in 1:length(start))
  assign(paste0("dataset_", i), read.table(text=data[start[i]:end[i]], sep=",", header=F))
```

**Answer to your comment:**

To combine those datasets, use (a.) either the `list` approach (if you need the seperate frames, too):

```
# 1st, create list 
datasets <- mapply(function(from, to) read.table(text=data[from:to], 
                                                sep=",", 
                                                header=F), 
                  start, 
                  end, 
                  SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
# 2nd, combine elements into one data frame
dataset <- do.call(rbind, datasets)
```

Or (b.) directly combine the data frames in your loop (if you just need the final combined data frame):

```
dataset <- data.frame()
for (i in 1:length(start))
  dataset <- rbind(dataset, read.table(text=data[start[i]:end[i]], 
                                       sep=",", 
                                       header=F))
```

Comment: Or use a `list` like described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20831584/extracting-certain-rows-from-imported-data-in-r/20831898#20831898)

Comment: Thank you Luke! Though was the assign function necessary? Could the loop have been with just paste("dataset_", i)=read.table(....)??

Comment: I guess better for me to ask is, why is when I tried the loop without the assign command did the loop not work? Sounds pretty intuitive that paste(x,y) would create the stringxy which would be assigned to read.table(..)

Comment: Assign let's you create new objects with dynamic names. paste(...)=read.table would try to assign a data frame (return value of read.table) to a string constant (return value of paste). This does not work.

Comment: Thanks luke. With the datsets that were generated from the loop I am trying to bind them all row wise. I am encountering the same problem of feeding the loop element into the string. Here is the loop. What am I missing?

Comment: x=dataset1;
for (i in 2:n-1){
  assign(x,rbind(x,paste("dataset",i)))
}